# How do you get/set content via javascript with the AJAX Control Toolkit HTML Editor?

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit, html-editor

I'm using the AJAX Control toolkit HTML editor and have what I hope is a simple question. As the question title says - how do you get/set the content of the HTML editor via javascript?

I have no problems accessing the server side content property - but how to do it client side?

Any help gratefully received !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Html Editor is one of the unique Ajax Control Toolkit controls, becuase it does not inherit `AjaxControlToolkit.ExtenderControlBase` (server side) nor inherit `AjaxControlToolkit.BehaviorBase` (client side).

So you can't use `$find` javascript method to get access to the behavior instance on the client, It inherits `AjaxControlToolkit.ScriptControlBase` (server side) and `Sys.UI.Control` (client side).

To get access to control instance on the client, you use the control property on the DOM element it self as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//considering the editor is loaded.
var editorControl = $get("<%=editor.ClientID%>").control;

//1. For setting content:
editorContorl.set_content("Sample Content");

//2. For getting content:
var content = editorContorl.get_content();    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $find("editor").set_content("jQuery set content");
    alert($find("editor").get_content());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Above answers didn't work for me.
So I had to dig through html and got following working solution. its working for years now and survived many framework/OS/browsers update/upgrade.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var varcont = '<%=txtInstructions.ClientID %>' + '_ctl02_ctl00';
    //Get Content
    var content = document.getElementById(varcont).contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML; 

    //Set Content
    document.getElementById(varcont).contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML='<b>I rock</b>'
</script>
```