# Ajax rich text editor Vs Flash

Tags: asp.net, ajax, flash

I uses ajax rich text editor. I want to input a flash file into this editor. How can I do this. Please help me.

Comment: What do you mean by "input a flash file?" [RTF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) files can't contain Flash files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rich text editor is really an HTML editor. So you should be inserting same html fragment (`embed` or `object`) to link the flash file.

Typically, you have to customize the control to add your own button and on button click, use java-script API for the control to inset the html fragment. I am unable to find exact documentation for this java-script API - looks like you have to inspect actual control accessor for possible methods or ask on SO again. Here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342557/how-do-you-get-set-content-via-javascript-with-the-ajax-control-toolkit-html-edit) that use JS API to get/set entire html content.

Alternative is to use another rich text editor such as [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) or [TinyMice](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com) or [PunyMice](http://www.moxieforge.net/overview.php?project_id=9&category_id=5)

Comment: I input that into html editor in html view.                    <object width="550" height="400">
<embed src="Customisation/animals1.swf" width="550" height="400">
</embed>
</object>  But It is not OK. The editor is not work.